# How to edit popup window in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, popup

**I am retrieving data from SQL SERVER using SqlDatasource control and displaying it in asp.net gridview.**

for that GridView Control I want to edit that particular data which is displaying in the grid

if i click on a particular edit row then the data should display in a popup window and should display the selected record data in popup window. after editing and saving the data i want the  gridview to update.

how can i implement this feature in my app.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few links which may be helpful to you.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Edit-Update-Records-in-GridView-using-Modal-Popup-in-ASP.Net.aspx

http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/

http://forums.asp.net/p/1685721/4440319.aspx/1?Re+Fancy+Box+in+Gird+View

http://forums.asp.net/p/1683887/4433122.aspx/1?Re+I+need+help+appending+a+JQuery+modal+box

http://forums.asp.net/p/1660076/4335007.aspx/1?Re+show+gridview+within+dialog

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GridView.RowEditing` event. In it you have  `e.NewEditIndex` parameter from which you can fill your popup window data and save it back to the database after editing.